# Hibernate giving following error :Error-->could not execute query

Tags: hibernate, struts

I'm trying to get the record which is exactly match with month column(which is id column) but i'm not getting the matching record..I executed the query like this in sql db "select sheet from webSheet where month='Feb'" it is executed.In HQL it's not working..

My stackflow:

```
INFO: table found: soft.dbo.employee
SHEET DAO CLASS
Nov 18, 2011 12:57:12 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
Retrieve Sheet:::::::Feb
INFO: columns: [empid, time, empname]
Nov 18, 2011 12:57:12 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: foreign keys: []
Nov 18, 2011 12:57:12 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: indexes: [pk__employee__73a521ea]
Nov 18, 2011 12:57:12 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: table found: soft`enter code here`.dbo.webSheet
Nov 18, 2011 12:57:12 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: columns: [month, sheet]
Nov 18, 2011 12:57:12 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: foreign keys: []
Nov 18, 2011 12:57:12 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: indexes: [pk__websheet__69279377]
Nov 18, 2011 12:57:12 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: schema update complete
Hibernate: select websheet0_.sheet as col_0_0_ from webSheet websheet0_ where websheet0_.month=Feb
Error-->could not execute query
In opensheet class-->result
Nov 18, 2011 12:57:13 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 207, SQLState: S0001
Nov 18, 2011 12:57:13 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Invalid column name 'Feb'.
```

My code as follows:DataAccessDAO.java

```
 try{
       Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
       WebSheet ws=new WebSheet();
       ws.setMonth(month);
        txn=session.beginTransaction();
        query=session.createQuery("select ws.sheet from WebSheet as ws where ws.month="+month).list();

        System.out.println("result::::::::::"+query.size());
        String result=query.iterator().next().getSheet();

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.err.println("Error-->"+ex.getMessage());
        if(txn!=null){
          txn.rollback();
        }
    }
```

My Mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.MyApp.beans.WebSheet" table="webSheet">
 <id name="month" type="string">
   <generator class="assigned"/>
 </id>
 <property name="sheet" type="string"/>
 </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

My Pojo class:

```
public class WebSheet {
   private String month;
   private String sheet;
   /*setters and getters*****
```

Answer (score 5):

Query should be like this -

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from com.MyApp.beans.WebSheet as ws where ws.month=:mth");

query.setParameter("mth", month);

WebSheet wsObj = null;
String sheet = null;

Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();{
     wsObj = (WebSheet) it.next();
}
if(wsObj != null){
sheet = wsObj.getSheet();
}
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.It's giving following error now. Error-->java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.MyApp.beans.WebSheet

Comment: i have altered my answer now check.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is the one @anirudhamundada said.

But if you want to keep doing it wrong and unsecure, you must add  this:

```
query=session.createQuery("select ws.sheet from WebSheet as ws where ws.month='"+month + "'").list();
```

It looks like you are not returning a `String`.

Try

```
Object o = query.iterator().next().getSheet();
System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
```

What's the type?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.It's giving following error now.    Error-->java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.MyApp.beans.WebSheet

Comment: is ws.sheet returning an String? It might be a WebSheet

Comment: Can you tell me what can i do?

Comment: Object o = query.iterator().next().getSheet(); System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());

Comment: Sorry to say udo fholl, I'm getting same error===>java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.MyApp.beans.WebSheet